# Null Pointer Exception while starting an activity

Tags: android, pointers, exception, android-intent, null

I use this activity to display product information in a table layout. When there is no products or no product information, when I start this activity, I get a null pointer exception. How do I handle this?

```
 public void startSalesReportActivity() {

        Intent salesRepIntent = getMiAirlineActivity().getSalesReportActivityIntent();
        double netTotalValue = SalesUtil.calculateFlightTransactionTotal(purchaseDao, refundDao, getMiAirlineActivity());
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(netTotalValue);
        bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        salesRepIntent.putExtra(TOTAL_VALUE, String.valueOf(bigDecimal));
        startActivity(salesRepIntent);
    }
```

I am calling this method in the above activity to calculate my product information.

```
 public static double calculateFlightTransactionTotal(PurchaseDao purchaseDao, PurchaseRefundDao purchaseRefundDao, AirlineActivity activity) {
        double purchaseAmount = calculateFlightLegPurchaseTransactions(purchaseDao, activity);
        double refundAmount = calculateFlightLegRefundTransactions(purchaseRefundDao, activity);
        double netAmount = purchaseAmount - refundAmount;
        return (netAmount > 0) ? netAmount : 0;
    }
```

The line that causes NPE is at double netTotalValue =...

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.miairline, PID: 8096
                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.miairline.model.PurchaseDao.getSuccessfulTransactions()' on a null object reference
                                                                 at com.miairline.utils.SalesUtil.calculateFlightLegPurchaseTransactions(SalesUtil.java:43)
                                                                 at com.miairline.utils.SalesUtil.calculateFlightTransactionTotal(SalesUtil.java:35)
                                                                 at com.miairline.settings.SettingsFragment.startSalesReportActivity(SettingsFragment.java:1134)
                                                                 at com.miairline.settings.SettingsFragment$22.onClick(SettingsFragment.java:1114)
```

Comment: You didn't include the line of code where the crash occures at com.miairline.utils.SalesUtil.calculateFlightLegPurchaseTransactions(SalesUtil.java:43)

Comment: you're calling `getSuccessfulTransactions()` on a null object.

Comment: I have included it. Line 43 public double calculateFlightLeg....It is in the second code block.

Comment: Where are you calling `getSuccessfulTransactions()`?

Comment: If it is a small project, can you send me the project as zip, I will check that out and fix it if I can

Answer (score 1):

Put it into if...else statement.
for example,

```
if(value == null || value < 0)
{
      // Your code
}
else
{
}
```

or

```
if(!value==null)
{
      // Your code
}
else 
{
}
```

and for crashing problem use try..catch Block.

Comment: My value is a double and I cannot use the operator for a double value.

Comment: u can use if (value==null)

Comment: oh! I see use Double instead of double .  
   
 double is a primitive type, while Double being an Object . double cannot be null